# Seeking Item Rename Hotfix for Sitecore 8.2 Update 6

Tags: support

I'm trying to address the question of getting name changes of Sitecore items to publish - currently changes to the item name don't get propagated to the web database when we publish.  I gather this is a fairly well-known issue and there are hotfixes available for it, but these appear to be specific to the version of Sitecore being used (I'm on 8.2 Update 6) and finding the right version of the hotfix(es) to use is proving elusive.

Is there a compendium of what fix goes with my version and where to find it, or are these required to be referred to Sitecore Support on a case-by-case basis?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, yes. That is the only way you have any kind of backing, since these hotfixes are only tested on the specific versions they are released for.

But there are places you can look if you're willing to take on some of the testing burden on your own.

[Sitecore Support](https://github.com/SitecoreSupport) is on Github. While I don't know the specifics of the exact problem you are experiencing, this here *could* be what you're looking for.

- [Republish mode does not change item name if the "__revision" field is not updated.](https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.332663)

Otherwise browse through the repositories and (possibly) find what you're after.

- https://github.com/orgs/SitecoreSupport/repositories?q=item+name&type=&language=&sort=

I would still recommend going through official support channels however.